Unable to keep FullCalendar alive or update data inside it after an endpoint Patch
I'm unable to "rerender" my events after a patch in backend.
For context, this is my component arrange:
// Index.vue
<template>
  <section>
    <search-bar @update-templates="updateTemplates" @update-loading="updateLoading"/>
    <template-grid :data="templates" :loading="loading" @selected-templates="selectTemplates"/>
    <recurrence-map :templates="selectedTemplates"/>
  </section>
</template>

// Index.vue
methods: {
    updateTemplates(newTemplates) {
      this.selectedTemplates = [];
      this.templates = newTemplates;
    },
    updateLoading(newLoading) {
      this.selectedTemplates = [];
      this.loading = newLoading;
    },
    selectTemplates(template) {
      this.selectedTemplates = [template];
    },
  }

I pass my templates data from template-grid to recurrence-map, and using that approach I can use a watch lifehook inside my recurrence-map to fire a function to render my events.
Using my Watch, I can check if data is changed and render my events again with new data selected:
// recurrence-map-mixin.js
watch: {
        templates: {
            handler(newTemplates) {
                this.calendarOptions.events = this.createEventsTemplates(newTemplates);
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },

My problem is:
I can only render my events using watch hook, I have the same function over my mount of beforeMount and for some reason, my function can't complete the steps.
Inside my Mounted I check if there's any value in localStorage, and fire my function:
// recurrence-map-mixin.js
mounted() {
        console.log('Component is ready. Updating events...');

        this.calendarApi = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();
        console.log('Calendar api: ', this.calendarApi);

        setTimeout(() => {
            const storedData = localStorage.getItem('selectedTemplates');
            if (!storedData) {
                return;
            }

            const selectedTemplates = JSON.parse(storedData);
            console.log('Templates from localStorage:', selectedTemplates);
            if (selectedTemplates) {
                this.calendarOptions.events = this.createEventsTemplates(selectedTemplates);
            }
        }, 3000)
    },

Edit: templates props data and localStorage have the same data when component is created, they come from same source.
In this piece of code, everything is working as intended.
My incorrect piece of code starts now: My main function that creates my events.
// recurrence-map-mixin.js
createEventsTemplates(templates) {
            if (!templates || templates.length === 0) {
                return [];
            }
            console.log('first break point')
            let events = [];
            const daysOfWeek = [
                'time_monday',
                'time_tuesday',
                'time_wednesday',
                'time_thursday',
                'time_friday',
                'time_saturday',
                'time_sunday'];

            const dayIndexMap = {
                'time_sunday': 0,
                'time_monday': 1,
                'time_tuesday': 2,
                'time_wednesday': 3,
                'time_thursday': 4,
                'time_friday': 5,
                'time_saturday': 6
            };

            templates.forEach(templateArray => {
                console.log('second break point');
                if (!templateArray || !templateArray.length || typeof templateArray[0] !== 'object') {
                    return;
                }

                templateArray.forEach(template => {
                    console.log('third break point');

                    daysOfWeek.forEach((day) => {
                        if (!template[day] || template[day].length === 0) {
                            return;
                        }

                        const dayIndex = dayIndexMap[day];

                        template[day].forEach(time => {
                            console.log('forth break point');
                            events.push({
                                daysOfWeek: [dayIndex],
                                startTime: time,
                                endTime: this.calculateEndTime(time, template.duration_time || 60),
                                color: template.color,
                                data: template,
                                title: template.name,
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            return events;
        },

For context, using Watch hook, all my events are created my this function, but using mounted hook to get template from local storage or receiving as props, don't.
Using mounted hook I pass by 'first break point' and get 33 'second break point' (I have 33 templates in my local storage selected in this example) and my function stops there, my 'third break point' inside templateArray.forEach(template => {}) forEach is not executed and my events are not created.
I don't know what more I can do to make this works.
More libs and versions context:
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^6.1.11",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",

Thanks!

The question doesn't seem to need fullcalendar-5, etc tags. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's not shown where "template from local storage or receiving as props" data comes from and what it looks like. My understanding is there's race condition somewhere that naturally stops being an issue when a watcher is used.

@EstusFlask

First part of my Index.vue I show how do I pass data from components.
My watch shows how I use received props - naturally don't need to explicity props piece of code.
localStorage and props info are the same, I'll edit that in my original post.
I have a timeout to wait all data to load correct and after that, call createEvents function and both watch and mounted lifehook don't execute at the same time.


Pass from where? It's unknown what selectedTemplates = [template] and selectedTemplates = JSON.parse(storedData) are. This is what needs to be debugged, currently only you can do this
